# How can i hold the properties of model between the actions(asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

Here's my model:

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public int BaseTypeField { set; get; }

        public MyType UserTypeField { set; get; }
    }
```

In the first action, i passed a MyModel to the view normally:

```
public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        //do something with model.UserTypeField
        return View(model);
    }
```

In Action1View i can easily modify the model.BaseTypeField with HtmlHelper, but I dont wanna modify model.UserTypeField in this view(neither can i store it in HiddenFor).
Then Action1View submit the model to another action:

```
public ActionResult Action2(MyModel model)
    {
        //model.UserTypeField is lost here
        return View();
    }
```

Here comes the problem: how can i hold/save the model.UserTypeField except for something like Session??

Comment: why can't you put it in a hidden field?

Comment: The only way to keep it from losing with hidden field is:<%=Html.HiddenFor(o=>o.UserTypeField.EveryFieldInUserField.MaybeSomeOthers)%>. Is it too annoying??

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want to use session state, then your only option is to pass the information to the client and have him pass it back with his request.  One way you could do this would be with a cookie.  Another might be to use a hidden form field.  You would include the field in your response to Action1, and the browser would automatically submit it in the request to Action2 (assuming you're using a form POST to call the action).

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options to preserve state across controller actions:

1. Store it in a Hidden input element in the View (though I appreciate that you say you can't, and there are plenty of good reasons why that might be the case).
2. Store it in Session State.
3. Store it in your application database (but then, you may as well use Session State).
4. Store it in a cookie. You can create a HttpCookie and add it to HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies in Action1 and read it from HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies in Action2.

If you only have a small amount of data and have no reason to use Session State elsewhere, I'd probably go for the cookie option. But Session State is there for precisely this kind of purpose. Don't be afraid to use it if it's the right thing.

Comment: In my case, how can i store it in Hidden? <%=Html.HiddenFor(o=>o.UserTypeField)%> turns out that in Action2 (model.UserTypeField == null) == true

Answer (score 0):

Each action should have a parameter that has only properties for fields which you would like to accept from the request.  The rest of the object should be loaded from the data store again.  In other words, don't have Action2 take a property that takes in the whole model as it will allow your consumers to inadvertently alter more properties than they should be able to.

This may seem like a lot of work to do on every step, but you will save yourself many headaches by not having to do all of the validation for all the fields which you do not want changed.  It is also easy to load the rest of the model from the data store if you wrap it up in a function.

Answer (score 0):

TempData[] is intended to hold items between actions, but it does use the Session.  If keys are not marked using Keep, then they are removed once the next Action is executed.

If you wanted to avoid Session fullstop, then you would have to serialize your object and send it to the client in the view (in a hidden form variable for example) and then deserialize it back into Action2.

If you wanted to use TempData (which would be simplest unless you can't use session for some reason), the syntax would just be:

```
public ActionResult Action1()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    //do something with model.UserTypeField

    TempData["UserTypeField"] = model.UserTypeField;

    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Action2(MyModel model)
{
    model.UserTypeField = TempData["UserTypeField"];

    return View();
}
```